# Keras for learning a random multidimensional function(regression)

Tags: keras, regression, keras-layer

I am using Keras to learn the surface of a random function. Basically I am sampling bunch of points to be used as training data. I am using the following code to generate the network.

```
def create_model(optimizer='adam'):
    model = Sequential()
    units = 100
    dim= 6
    dropout= 1
    ## making the model graph, Stacking layers is done by .add():
    model.add(Dense(units=units, input_dim=dim, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout))

    model.add(Dense(units=units, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout))

    model.add(Dense(units=units, activation="sigmoid"))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout))
    model.add(Dense(units=1, activation = 'linear'))

    # optmiser = keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.001, rho=0.9, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)
    # optmiser = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)

    # configure the model's learning process; loss and optimisation etc
    model.compile(loss='mse',
                  optimizer=optimizer, metrics=["accuracy"])

    return model
```

I am getting the following logs during training,

```
451/667 [===================>..........] - ETA: 0s - loss: nan - acc: 0.0000e+00
```

I think I am doing something wrong in creating the network or the choice of different parameter. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks,

Comment: Dropout with p = 1 means the network won't learn anything.

Comment: yep, that's was a prob. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The input to `Dropout` represents the fraction of the input units to drop (see [here](https://keras.io/layers/core/#dropout)). Thus, by doing

```
model.add(Dropout(dropout))
```

with `dropout=1`, you basically throw away all the units. You need to choose `dropout` strictly smaller than 1.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.That solves the problem. Also I figured out that I am using `metrics=["accuracy"]` which is wrong in this case as it is a regression task.